# ROS Noetic Issue with linking with LibTorch and class_loader

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I created a simple nodelet which was functioning correctly in ROS Melodic. However, when I moved to ROS Noetic I have encountered the following issue when running a launch file:

```
 /opt/ros/noetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet: symbol lookup error: /home/benksy/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libnodelet_plugins.so: undefined symbol: _ZN12class_loader4impl30getCurrentlyLoadingLibraryNameEv".
```

It corresponds to class_loader::impl::getCurrentlyLoadingLibraryName().

I attempted solutions from here https://answers.ros.org/question/291910/linking-problem-with-catkin_libraries/ but with no success.

I presume there is a quick solution but I am not that familiar with CMake/C++ so any help appreciated.

Update 1:

I have noticed that the error pops up when I try to link Torch/LibTorch library to my nodelet. When target_link_libraries does not include ${TORCH_LIBRARIES}, the error does not show up.

Here is an example of CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(random_pkg)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/benksy/libtorch")

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  nodelet
  roscpp
  rospy
  roslib
 )

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

## Setup include directories
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})


catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#   LIBRARIES nodelet_test_plugins
#   CATKIN_DEPENDS
#    lidar_msgs
#    roscpp
#    rospy
#    std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

## Create the nodelet tutorial library
add_library(nodelet_test_plugins
            src/test.cpp
            src/test.h
           )

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(nodelet_test_plugins ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PROJECT_LIBRARIES} ${TORCH_LIBRARIES})

if(catkin_EXPORTED_LIBRARIES)
  add_dependencies(nodelet_test_plugins ${catkin_EXPORTED_LIBRARIES})
endif()

## Mark the nodelet library for installations
install(TARGETS nodelet_test_plugins
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})

install(FILES nodelet_test_plugins.xml mynodelet.launch
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
```

All other files are empty/dummy.

test.cpp:

```
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
#include "test.h"

PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(random_pkg::Test, nodelet::Nodelet)

namespace random_pkg
{
  void Test::onInit()
  {}
}
```

test.h

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <nodelet/nodelet.h>

namespace random_pkg
{
  class Test : public nodelet::Nodelet
  {
    public:
      Test(){}
    private:
      virtual void onInit();
    };
}
```

nodelet_test_plugins.xml

```
<library path="libnodelet_test_plugins">
  <class name="random_pkg/Test" type="random_pkg::Test" base_class_type="nodelet::Nodelet">
    <description>
      Write things here.
    </description>
  </class>

</library>
```

random.launch (When this file is launched the above error shows up)

```
<launch>

  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="standalone_nodelet"  args="manager" output="screen"/>

  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="Test" args="load random_pkg/Test standalone_nodelet" output="screen">
  </node>

</launch>
```

Other info:
ROS Noetic/Ubuntu 20.04, gcc 9.3.0, LibTorch 1.9.0 (tried both CPU and GPU Cuda 11.1)

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384800/ros-noetic-issue-with-linking-with-libtorch-and-class_loader/) by [BenQ1110](https://answers.ros.org/users/49273/benq1110/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2021-08-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2021-08-20**:
Please provide enough information to reproduce your problem otherwise it's very hard to help you.

**Comment by [BenQ1110](https://answers.ros.org/users/49273/benq1110/) on 2021-08-20**:
I updated the post. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found a solution, and it is directly torch related.

When using gcc>=5.1 (as in Ubuntu 20.4/ROS Noetic), you have to use a cxx11 ABI version of the LibTorch package. Otherwise, you cannot link the libraries.

It is explained here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/issues-linking-with-libtorch-c-11-abi/29510/11, and https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/17492.

---

Originally posted by [BenQ1110](https://answers.ros.org/users/49273/benq1110/) with karma: 36 on 2021-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1